# Read from Hbase table and write to another Hbase table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I want a simple code which read from Hbase table, then modify the existing row key and the write that modified rowKey to another hbase table. Here I want the Map Reduce job. As I want some calculation have to do in Reducer.

Is an example available for this?

Comment: have you tried anything, please post your sample code, or what have you tried . as your code can be written in many forms

Comment: Requests for examples are firmly off-topic here. It is better to show what you have tried or what research you have done, so readers can appreciate the technical direction you are looking into.